# SQLite FTS4: A query containing a single unary not expression?

Tags: sql, sqlite, full-text-search

The SQLite3 FTS4 [documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_3_2) regarding the standard query unary `-` operator states:

> An FTS query may not consist entirely of terms or term-prefix queries
>   with unary "-" operators attached to them.

Is there any way around this?  Specifically, I want to retrieve all the rows in my table that *do not* contain a term or term-prefix.

```
sqlite> select * from search;
1|Clock
2|Un
sqlite> select id from search where text match 'Un';
2
sqlite> select id from search where text match 'clock -Un';
1
sqlite> select id from search where text match '-Un';
Error: malformed MATCH expression: [-Un]
sqlite> select id from search where text match '-Un*';
Error: malformed MATCH expression: [-Un*]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id
from search
where docid not in (select docid
                    from search
                    where text match 'Un')
```